# Operate multiple in operations in Firestore. Any hack possible?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query on multiple fields based on multiple `in` conditions as shown below:

```
db
    .collection(firebasePaths.funfuse_verified_users)
    .orderBy('uid')
    .where('uid', 'not-in', notToIncludeAccounts)
    .orderBy('skills')
    .where('skills', 'in', skills)
    .orderBy('interests')
    .where('interests', 'in', interests)
```

Firestore limitation states that only one `in` is allowed per query but I was interested in knowing if by some hacky way can I make this work? One thing I thought of is to fetch the two results and then take the intersection of those but this would mean a lot of load on my backend.
Is there some other way that I am not aware of which could be used for such scenarios? I want to filter the database based on skills and interest arrays.

**Edit 1: Added Document Example**
Example of the document will be something like this:

```
{
      "name": "Shivam",
      "online": true,
      "bio": "",
      "skills": [
        "Supply Chain",
        "Inventory Management",
        "Legal",
        "Digital Marketing",
        "Web"
      ],
      "interests": [
        "Healthcare"
      ],
      "imageLoc": "profile-pics/profile-photo",
      "isImageAvailable": true,
      "uid": "",
      "username": "tttt"
    },
```

Expected query:

```
db
    .collection(firebasePaths.funfuse_verified_users)
    .orderBy('uid')
    .where('uid', 'not-in', ['1','2'])
    .orderBy('skills')
    .where('skills', 'in', ["Supply Chain","Inventory Management"])
    .orderBy('interests')
    .where('interests', 'in', ["Supply Chain","Inventory Management"])
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing hidden in the API to allow the use-case, so any workaround will have to come from changes to the data model.

---

The best I can think of is to add an additional field that combines the `skills` and `interests` values, and filter on that.

If you just add all the individual values ("skills_and_interests": ["Supply Chain", "Inventory Management", "Legal", "Digital Marketing", "Web", "Healthcare"]), you can do the equivalent of an OR operation on that with `in`. If you want to be able to distinguish skills from interesting, you could prefix the values (`"skill_Supply Chain"`, `"interest_Healthcare"`).

If you want to filter on combined values, you'd have to add the combinations of skills and interests (e.g. `"Supply Chain_Healthcare", "Inventory Management_Healthcare"`), so that you can then do an AND like operation.